# NodeJS module installers do not set PATH variable

Tags: node.js, path

For some reason on my current and previous pc, installing modules in NodeJS does not create PATH variables (Using windows 7/10). I managed to get the modules working in the past by manually editing my PATH variables, but it would be "cool" if NodeJS could do this for me...

I have just downloaded and installed NodeJS and Weinre again. npm gets added to the path variable, Weinre does not. (The same thing happend with Ionic a few weeks back, so had uninstalled it to try it again later).

I am running the command line prompt as an administrator.

Another thing which confuses me, which might be the cause of the problem is the following. I have installed NodeJS in:

```
    C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

But running "npm -g ls" gives me the following result:

```
    C:\>npm -g ls
    C:\Program Files\IBM\RAD9.1\cordova_cli
    └─┬ weinre@2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV
    ├─┬ express@2.5.11
    │ ├─┬ connect@1.9.2
    │ │ └── formidable@1.0.17
    │ ├── mime@1.2.4
    │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
    │ └── qs@0.4.2
    ├─┬ nopt@3.0.4
    │ └── abbrev@1.0.7
    └── underscore@1.7.0
```

I have IBM Rational Application Developer installed, and it seems like NodeJS refers to this installation folder... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output of `npm prefix -g` matches `C:\Program Files\IBM\RAD9.1\cordova_cli` then everything is behaving as expected. You can either change your global npm prefix to your Node.js executable and reinstall the npm packages, or just add the current prefix to your `PATH`.

I would probably another clean reinstall of Node.js and npm. Before doing so, make sure to manually delete any existing npm modules and configs:

1. Run `npm config ls -l`, find the `globalconfig` line, and delete that file.
2. Go to the output directory of `npm prefix -g` and delete any `node` and `node_modules` files or directories.
3. Uninstall node as usual

Comment: tyvm! Changing the prefix location in the file "_C:\Users\user\.npmrc_" to
"_prefix = C:\Program Files\nodejs_" solved both the incorrect installation directory as the failure to create the PATH variable!